# Pagination using skip and take methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var skip = selectedPage*pageSize;
            var take = Math.Min(result.DataSourceCount - skip, pageSize);

            List<SENTINEL_OPERATION> results = sentinelOperationManager.SearchSentinelOperations(sid).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

My last page always gets empty. Im using a PageDataSource to get the pagesize and sending the clicked page using jquery ajax get. Did i miss something? Thanks

Comment: Does selectedPage start from 1 or 0?

Comment: For the `take` amount you can just use `pageSize` - it's no problem if the supplied list is smaller.

Comment: @alun It starts at 1 so I added -1, seems to be working now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I bet, that `selectedPage` starts from 1 in your code and this is causing erros. Then you get `skip == pageSize` when on first page, and you go "out of range" on last page, but you are skipping the "real" first page.

If `selectedPage` starts from `1`, then change this formula to:

```
var skip = (selectedPage - 1 ) * pageSize;
```

Also - there is no need to manually calculate `take` value. You can just pass `pageSize` and it will always work. If your data source will not contain enough elements, nothing wrong will happen, just elements that are available will be returned.

Comment: Just noticed the first part. This is correct. Ill adjust the take-part as well, thanks!